# Lasso regression does not work properly in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidymodels, lasso-regression

I was trying to replicate Julia Silge's great lesson on [**Lasso regression using tidymodel**](https://juliasilge.com/blog/lasso-the-office/) but even if the data cleaning gives exactly the same result, I have found that the same coding for the regression gives a completely different result, which then messes up the whole prediction phase.

A reproducible example is the following:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(schrute)
library(janitor)
tidymodels_prefer()

# Load data
ratings_raw <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-03-17/office_ratings.csv")
#> Rows: 188 Columns: 6
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (1): title
#> dbl  (4): season, episode, imdb_rating, total_votes
#> date (1): air_date
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
schrute::theoffice
#> # A tibble: 55,130 × 12
#>    index season episode episode_name director   writer           character text 
#>    <int>  <int>   <int> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>            <chr>     <chr>
#>  1     1      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Michael   All …
#>  2     2      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Jim       Oh, …
#>  3     3      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Michael   So y…
#>  4     4      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Jim       Actu…
#>  5     5      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Michael   All …
#>  6     6      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Michael   Yes,…
#>  7     7      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Michael   I've…
#>  8     8      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Pam       Well…
#>  9     9      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Michael   If y…
#> 10    10      1       1 Pilot        Ken Kwapis Ricky Gervais;S… Pam       What?
#> # ℹ 55,120 more rows
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: text_w_direction <chr>, imdb_rating <dbl>,
#> #   total_votes <int>, air_date <chr>

# We wish to join up the two data sets. We need to change the way
# season and episodes are counted. So we need to do some work to join them up
remove_regex <- "[:punct:]|[:digit:]|parts |part |the |and"
office_ratings <- ratings_raw |> 
    transmute(episode_name = str_to_lower(title),
              episode_name = str_remove_all(episode_name, remove_regex),
              episode_name = str_trim(episode_name),
              imdb_rating)

office_info <- schrute::theoffice |> 
    mutate(season = as.numeric(season),
           episode = as.numeric(episode),
           episode_name = str_to_lower(episode_name),
           episode_name = str_remove_all(episode_name, remove_regex),
           episode_name = str_trim(episode_name)) |> 
    select(season, episode, episode_name, director, writer, character)

# Let us count how many line every character has per episode
characters <- office_info |> 
    count(episode_name, character) |> 
    add_count(character, wt = n, name = "character_count") |> 
    filter(character_count > 800) |> 
    select(-character_count) |> 
    pivot_wider(names_from = character, 
                values_from = n,
                values_fill = list(n = 0))

# We want to do the same for writer and directors
creators <- office_info |> 
    distinct(episode_name, director, writer) |> 
    pivot_longer(director:writer, names_to = "role", values_to = "person") |> 
    separate_rows(person, sep = ";") |> 
    add_count(person) |> 
    filter(n > 10) |> 
    distinct(episode_name, person) |> 
    mutate(person_value = 1) |> 
    pivot_wider(names_from = person,
                values_from = person_value,
                values_fill = list(person_value = 0))

office <- office_info |> 
    distinct(season, episode, episode_name) |> 
    inner_join(characters) |> 
    inner_join(creators) |> 
    inner_join(office_ratings) |> 
    janitor::clean_names()
#> Joining with `by = join_by(episode_name)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(episode_name)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(episode_name)`
#> Warning in inner_join(inner_join(inner_join(distinct(office_info, season, : Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y`.
#> ℹ Row 71 of `x` matches multiple rows in `y`.
#> ℹ Row 79 of `y` matches multiple rows in `x`.
#> ℹ If a many-to-many relationship is expected, set `relationship =
#>   "many-to-many"` to silence this warning.


# Training the model
# We are going to use a lasso regression model
set.seed(1234)
office_split <- initial_split(office, strata = season)
office_train <- training(office_split)
office_test <- testing(office_split)

# Let us use a recipe
office_rec <- recipe(imdb_rating ~ ., data = office_train) |> 
    update_role(episode_name, new_role = "ID") |> # It is no longer a predictor
    step_zv(all_numeric(), - all_outcomes()) |> 
    step_normalize(all_numeric(), - all_outcomes())

office_prep <- office_rec |> 
    prep(strings_as_factors = FALSE)

# We can now train the model
lasso_spec <- linear_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) |> 
    set_engine("glmnet")

wf <- workflow() |> 
    add_recipe(office_rec)

lasso_fit <- wf |> 
    add_model(lasso_spec) |> 
    fit(data = office_train)

lasso_fit %>%
    pull_workflow_fit() %>%
    tidy()
#> Warning: `pull_workflow_fit()` was deprecated in workflows 0.2.3.
#> ℹ Please use `extract_fit_parsnip()` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> 
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack
#> 
#> Loaded glmnet 4.1-8
#> # A tibble: 31 × 3
#>    term        estimate penalty
#>    <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 (Intercept)  8.37        0.1
#>  2 season       0           0.1
#>  3 episode      0           0.1
#>  4 andy         0           0.1
#>  5 angela       0.00234     0.1
#>  6 darryl       0           0.1
#>  7 dwight       0           0.1
#>  8 jim          0.00150     0.1
#>  9 kelly        0           0.1
#> 10 kevin        0           0.1
#> # ℹ 21 more rows
```

The outcome that she gets is instead the following:

[image]

Can someone please explain me what is happening here, because I don't really know what do do to make this regression work.

Comment: Try `lasso_fit |> extract_fit_engine() |> tidy() |> arrange(step)`. I don't have a good understanding of how `pull_workflow_fit()` may have changed or if that was a typo originally, but the results seem to have the structure you're after.

Comment: When Julia created that blog post, the now deprecated `pull_workflow_fit()` used to extract the engine fit (so the glmnet fit directly), while now it extracts the parsnip fit. Hence the difference in table structure. You'll still see differences in coefficients because the seed for the random number generator isn't being set.